# Facebook API: How to tag all the people who liked your page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, photo-tagging

Say I have a Facebook `page` and there are `n` number of people who `liked` that page. Now I want to upload a photo on this page and tag all the people who `liked` that page. Is this possible? If so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, for several reasons:

1. You can't retrieve a list of all fans of a page via the API
2. You can only tag friends of the current user whose access token you're using in photos
3. It's against policy to tag people in photos in which they don't actually appear